# Fetch urls prefixed with username:password@

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, net-http

I am using `net-http-persistent` gem to fetch pages. It works perfectly fine for most of the cases. But, recently I noted that it returns 401 for urls prefixed with username:password@ e.g. https://username:password@somesite.com. If i try other options like `excon`/`curl` they fetch such pages without problem. I saw the logs of the requests made by Net::HTTP::Persistent and found out net::http totally discards the username:password part while connecting to the server.

Can anybody help me how to make Net::HTTP::Persistent make use of `username:password@` part.

----------------------EDITED--------------------

Sample code:

```
url = "https://user:pass@example.com/feed"
uri = URI(url)
http = Net::HTTP::Persistent.new
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.request uri
http.shutdown

response.code # yields 401 which it should not as url has username and password.


#Incase of excon, if you do 

response = Excon.get(url)
response.status # yields 200 as it is making use of username:password prefix
```

Comment: Show the code which fail.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, just edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/drbrain/net-http-persistent/issues/75), try code like:

```
uri = URI("https://example.com/feed")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'

http = Net::HTTP::Persistent.new
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

response = http.request uri, req
http.shutdown

puts response.code
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Although instead of `response = http.request req`, it should be `response = http.request uri, req`. First param should be `uri` and we can pass `request obj` as 2nd param.

Source: https://github.com/drbrain/net-http-persistent/issues/27#issuecomment-6564122